# appending in pandas - row wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I'm trying to append two columns of my dataframe to an existing dataframe with this:
 `dataframe.append(df2, ignore_index = True)`

and this does not seem to be working.
This is what I'm looking for (kind of) --> a dataframe with 2 columns and 6 rows:

[image]

although this is not correct and it's using two print statements to print the two dataframes, I thought it might be helpful to have a selection of the data in mind.

I tried to use concat(), but that leads to some issues as well.
`dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, df2])`
but that appears to concat the second dataframe in columns rather than rows, in addition to gicing NaN values:
[image]

any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this happened because your dataframes have different column names. Try assigning the second dataframe column names with the first dataframe column names.

```
df2.columns = dataframe.columns
dataframe_new = pd.concat([dataframe, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: That worked! I can't believe I didn't notice that earlier! Thank you so much!

Comment: glad it helped.